# JavaScript apply()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, apply

When I pass an array and Object respectively to function.apply(), I get the o/p of NaN but when I do it Object and array, I get a Number. Why is this happening?

since arrays are also considered as objects, why I'm unable to use this to represent array from the same context/

I've tried changing the position of variable calling but I know for a fact that the order only matters when it's a parameter.

```js
function add() {
  return arr[0] + arr[1] + this.a + this.b;
}
let obj = {
  a: 1,

  b: 2
};

let arr = [1, 2];

console.log(add.apply(arr, obj));
console.log(add.apply(obj, arr));
```

O/P

```
NaN
6
```

Comment: When you use `add.apply(arr, obj)`, `this` will be `arr`. And there is no `a` and `b` property in `arr`

Comment: *I know for a fact that the order only matters when it's a parameter.*. Not in this case. Your second one works.

Comment: Your `add` function doesn't even have parameters. So applying a list of arguments doesn't even matter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a diagram could help.  Your function uses no parameters, so what you supply in the second argument to `apply` (which should be an array of values) doesn't matter.  Only the first parameter (which becomes `this` in the function body) matters.

When you call with `arr`, then `this` points to the `arr` supplied in the argument, but `arr` also points to the same object, as it's global and not overwritten anywhere:

```js
function add() {
  //        1     +   1    + undefined + undefined   //=> NaN
    return arr[0] + arr[1] + this.a    + this.b;
} //        |        |         |           |
  // +------+--------+---------+-----------+
  // |                       
  // V                       
let arr = [1, 2];         let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
  //                           ^
  //                            `-----Nothing points to this

add.apply(arr) // equivalent to `add.apply(arr, obj)`, since `add` ignores parameters
```

When you call with `obj`, then `this` points to the `obj` supplied in the argument, and `arr` again points to the global `arr` object:

```js
function add() {
  //         1    +   2    +   1       +    2        //=> 6 
    return arr[0] + arr[1] + this.a    + this.b;
} //        |        |         |           |
  // +------+--------+         +-----------+
  // |                         |   
  // V                         V  
let arr = [1, 2];         let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};

add.apply(obj) // equivalent to `add.apply(obj, arr)`, since `add` ignores parameters
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, whatever the parameter given in the first position is considered as ```this```.

Comment: @Dev_noob: Exactly.  And the array supplied in the second gives the remaining parameters to your function.  In your case, there are none, so it's ignored.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

`function.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])` your first argument becomes `this` in the function, and second argument is an array of arguments youre passing to the function

so `add.apply(arr, obj)` really should be `add.apply(arr, [obj])` would translate to the following, which `this(arr)` doesnt have properties `a` nor `b`

```js
function add() {
  return arr[0] + arr[1] + arr.a + arr.b;
}
// then invoking it as 
add(obj);
```

and `add.apply(obj, arr)` would translate to

```js
function add() {
  return arr[0] + arr[1] + obj.a + obj.b;
}
// them invoking it as 
add(1, 2);
```

Comment: What is `function add(1, 2)` supposed to mean? You can't put numbers in the parameter list.

Comment: second argument of `function.prototype.apply` is an array of arguments used to invoke the method itself, so when OP did `add.apply(obj, arr)`, hes basically invoking the method with those 2 arguments, even though his function doesnt receive arguments, but hes invoking them with arguments

Comment: Right, he's calling `add(1, 2)`, but that's not the same as putting the numbers in the parameter list in the definition.

Comment: right, lemme see if i can edit it to make it more clear